# Node JS Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu

i'm trying to run this script :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
 });

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I keep getting this error :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue 
(/home/yassine/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake 
(/home/yassine/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect 
(/home/yassine/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yassine/demo_db_connection.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04 . 
Can anybody assist with this please ..

Comment: is `yourusername` a regular MySQL user ? with connection permission from `localhost` ?

Comment: i'm using 'root' as username and the password that i set during installation as a password

Comment: how do i verify that i have connection permission from localhost please ?

Comment: from your favorite terminal, run `mysql -u root -p`, enter the root password then you'll know if `root` is authorized to connect from localhost. If not, then you have a problem...

Comment: or it can simply mean that your mysql service is not started

Comment: All done , i'm authorized to connect from localhost and i restarted mysql service , but the error is still there ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187193/discussion-between-dun32-and-yassine-el-baaj).